# How to access Split / "vertex-per-face" normals in Geometry Nodes 3.0+?

Tags: normals, geometry-nodes

I want to use the custom normals already present in my geometry but the Normal node only seems to output generated smooth normals.
The spreadsheet only contains one normal vector per face, I don't need this type of normal and want to output our split normals as vertex colors without compromising auto-smoothing, sharp edges or faces marked as flat.
How can this be done in Geometry nodes?

Comment: I don't think that it is possible at the moment, I cannot get even custom vertex normals